# how to update a firestore map field with react js map data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I couldn't add every cart items as a map to firestore database.

It replaces with the last data even with { merge: true }

```
      cartItems.map((item) =>
        updateDoc(
          docRef,
          {
            CartItems: {
              [`${item.productName}`]: item.imgUrl[0],
            },
          },
          { merge: true }
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `{ merge: true }` Firestore leaves any data for fields that you don't specify unmodified. It does however *replace* the value of fields that you *do* specify, and does not merge them as you seem to want.

---

If your `CartItems` is an array, you can [use the `array-union` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) to add an item to it:

```
updateDoc(
  docRef,
  {
    CartItems: {
      [`${item.productName}`]: arrayUnion([item.imgUrl[0]]),
    },
  },
  { merge: true }
)
```

---

It seems that your `CartItem` is a map, not an array. In that case you can [use `.` notation to update the nested field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects):

```
const path = `CartItems.${item.productName}`;
updateDoc(
  docRef,
  {
    [path]: item.imgUrl[0]
  },
  { merge: true }
)
```